# Mathematical Image representation

Tags: image, image-processing

```
Let I(V) -> R^3 be an image defined on a set of pixels V.
```

This is common line which I come across in most of the research papers related to image processing. I am confused about the `R^3` factor here. Does it represent the RGB model or something else?

Context : [www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~carreira/papers/cvpr2010_2.pdf](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~carreira/papers/cvpr2010_2.pdf)

Comment: You should provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when the pixel values are tuples, the image must be multispectral. And in the particular case of three components, red/green/blue channels are the most likely.